# The intersection of two theories is a theory.

Tags: logic, proof-verification

How to prove that the intersection of two theories is a theory ?

Let the theories be $T_1, T_2$

The only thing i know about a theory is that for all $A$ such that $T \vDash A$ $\to$ $A \in T$

So i tried . Let $B $ be a first order formula. Such that $T_1, T_2 \vDash B$

We know that because $T_1$ is a theory $B \in T1$ . Similiarly $B\in T_2$ So $B\in T_1 \cap T_2 $

Is my proof correcct ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: I believe that you should use the symbol for derivability $\vdash$, $T\vdash A$ instead of $T\models A$.

Comment: It is interesting that this theorem can be generalized. First, from two theories to any set of theories. Second, from the derivability relation to an abstract consequence relation. For example, theories can be replaced with algebraic substructures. An algebraic substructure is a subset of an underlying set of an algebraic structure closed with respect to algebraic operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments:

- "Such that $T_1, T_2\models B$" should be "such that $T_1\cap T_2\models B$" - to show that $T_1\cap T_2$ is a theory, you start with a sentence it proves (and then show that that sentence is in it).
- You implicitly use the fact that ince $T_1\cap T_2\models A$, $T_1\models A$ (before "we know that because").  Given that this is an exercise in establishing the basics, it's probably a good idea to say *why* this is true.

Other than that, looks good!

Comment: Should i say because $T_1 \cap T_2  \subseteq T_1$ and that the set of consequences of $T_1 \cap T_2 \subseteq$ the set of consequences of $T_1$ ? Or is there an easier way to show why ?

Comment: @asddf That's exactly it.